# Heroku: how to programatically restart or shut down a dyno from an application running on that dyno

Tags: heroku

I have a scrapy scraper running on Heroku. I want to restart the scraper as soon as it finishes. What is the best way to achieve this?

- The obvious solution would be to kill or restart that dyno, then Heroku will rerun the scraper via the procfile. However, it's not clear what the best way to do this is.

Related: does Heroku automatically detect that your process has stopped running and automatically shut down the dyno for you? Or does the dyno just sit there doing nothing?

Related #2: could you call a python script/program from within your scraper just before it exits, then that script could wait 5 seconds and then execute

```
scrapy runspider myspider
```

Would that work? Presumably trying to execute

```
scrapy runspider myspider
```

from *within* the spider itself will cause the universe to implode or something (twisted error probably)?

Comment: answering my own questions: > "want to restart the scraper as soon as it finishes. What is the best way to achieve this?"   ----- the best way to do this is to create a "master" script with a while loop which uses `subprocess.call ` to repeatedly call instances of scrapy. The Heroku procfile runs the master script.

However, the original question is still unanswered: how to you kill a dyno from within itself in heroku?

Answer (score 0):

The following code repeatedly runs a spider, re-running it when it finishes, using `subprocess`. Assume that this code is in a file called `myScript.py`

```
import subprocess

while True:

   subprocess.call(["scrapy", "runspider", "myspider.py"])
```

The procfile should reference that script instead of the actual scraper as follows:

```
myHerokuScrapingProcess: python myScript.py
```

I still don't know how to restart the actual dyno though.